How is the insert operation in a B-Tree O(log n), should it not be O( log 2d -1 ) where d is the degree of the B-Tree
A search operation in B-Tree can be O(logn) because we can perform a binary search on the key we are looking for at any node. When inserting a key in a B-Tree node which isn't full and is the leaf node, we would need to scan all the elements of the node to make an insertion in the sorted order, so the worst case time complexity would be O(2d-1) where d = Degree of the B-Tree.
Example:
B-Tree degree = 3
Max Items = 2(3) - 1
If my B-Tree has just a root node which isn't full then inserting a value 98 in the below node will require me to shift all my keys one slot to the right to maintain the sort order, which means I would need to go through all my keys to insert the key at the right position making it O ( 2d - 1 ), where d = degree of B-Tree.
| 99 | 100 | 101 | 102 | NULL |

After insertion
| 98 | 99 | 100 | 101 | 102 |

I would like to understand how the insert operation has a time complexity of O ( log n ).

Write some code.  It's easier to talk about a concrete implementation.  You search to find where to insert node which is a O(logn)  in a balanced tree), and once you find the spot you do no more than O(logn) work to insert the node.  Using the algorithm in the Corman book you split notes going from the root to the leaf which is at most O(logn) hight, and the actual operations at each node is O(k).

Yes, but once we find the node  we would still need to do a linear scan in the node itself to find the position for the new key, so in that case would it not be O(log n) * (2d-1) where d = degree of the tree.

d is a constant.  (2d-1) * O(log n) = O(log n)

okay, understood. Thanks for clearing it up.

2d -1 are the max number of keys a node can contain right ?  d -1 is the min number of items, assuming my node is almost full but short by one key which would make it 2d - 2 ( after dropping the -2 ) it would be O (log 2d).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree says between m/2 and m keys per node.  Between d and 2d-1 is fine, too.
